# Getting select labels without save into state?

Tags: reactjs

Hello after experimenting with useState to add items and rendering it at same time from what i've been selected, now im kinda confused how to show the label because im only saving the id to the state for submitting to API.

here's my select options:

```
const medicine = [
  { id_obat: '123', label: 'Amoxcilin 300mg' },
  { id_obat: '321', label: 'Ibuprofen 500ml' }
];

              <Input
                type="select"
                name="id_obat"
                value={id_obat}
                onChange={onChange}
              >
                <option value="" hidden>
                  Select&hellip;
                </option>
                {medicine.map(med => (
                  <option key={med.id_obat} value={med.id_obat}>
                    {med.label}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </Input>
```

im saving it into my array state like this:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState([]);
const [meds, setMeds] = useState({
    id_obat: '',
    cara_pakai: '',
    kuantitas: ''
  });

  const onChange = e => {
    setMeds({ ...meds, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    console.log(meds);
  };

  const addMed = () => {
    setValues([...values, meds]);
    console.log(values);
  };
```

as you can see im only saving the id_obat, but at the same time i render what item that already selected and added into array. i know to show the label if not at the same time but this i dont know.

here's how i render my selected items:

```
          <p>{' Medication List'}</p>
          <hr />
          <Col style={{ maxHeight: '240px', overflowY: 'auto' }}>
            {values.map((value, idx) => (
              <Card key={idx}>
                <CardBody>
                  <h6>
                    {value.id_obat}
                    <small>{' qty: ' + value.kuantitas}</small>
                    <br />
                    <small>{value.cara_pakai}</small>
                  </h6>
                </CardBody>
              </Card>
            ))}
```

now i'm wondering how to render the selected item label without adding label to the state. because im only saving the the id value. I cant think right now, honestly :)

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox example reproducing your issue like thi?? https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-glitter-xm3xs ..

Comment: you can try `value={med}` instead of `value={med.id_obat}`. This way you can save both id_obat & label in state. let me know if this works